# tomcat died after running well for a while

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, c3p0

i have 2 tomcat server running on the same machine, both accessing the same DB on another machine.

```
Tomcat 7.0.37 with spring 4.1.6 (MVC, jdbc, framework), and MySQL 5.5.13.
```

the tomcat web server works well for hours until it suddenly died with no response.

i have to kill the process manually as the bin/shutdown.sh has no effect.

when tomcat1 dies, tomcat2 still works well...

things i tried:

```
1 increased the c3p0 max_connections from 50 to 100
2 change tomcat to NIO mode
```

will try:

```
replace c3p0 with HikariCP;
```

here is the log from catalina.out:

```
2015-12-07 22:13:55,899 ERROR [com.yd.api.controller.YDTagController] - <org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.>
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:772)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:226)
    at com.yundong.api.dao.impl.YDTagDaoImpl.getUploaderCount(YDTagDaoImpl.java:587)
    at com.yundong.api.service.impl.YDTagServiceImpl.getUploaderCount(YDTagServiceImpl.java:373)
    at com.yundong.api.controller.YDTagController.searchActivityphotoByTag(YDTagController.java:385)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor279.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:527)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@d1003e1 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1317)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: did you read the first couple lines? Figure out what happened to your database...

Comment: @MarcB thanks for your formatting. the mysql database works well as another application is accessing even the same table.

Comment: There is nothing transaction related in your stack trace (I would expect a `TransactionInterceptor`. Without transaction demarcation you can run into pool starvation issues (i.e. connections not returned to the pool). Next to that I wouldn't use C3P0 anymore I strongly suggest a pool like `HikariCP` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum we decide  move to HikariCP and try again later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on the DB locally, then you can check the timeout settings and modify them in order to cope with the delay in the request calls.

If you are working on a remote DB m/c, then maintaining a consistent Connection is needed. If you are unsure about how to keep the connection consistent with your machine to the DB machine, then write a simple batch script which pings the DB server and keeps the Connection alive for your application to send a request.

Comment: i have 2 applications running on the same web server, both accessing the same DB server. as tomcat1 dies, tomcat2 works well...

Comment: so definitely this is a problem with a connections in your application. Make sure you are closing them properly.

Comment: would u pls give me further info on timeout setting ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a process got stuck waiting for a new sql connection.

- Make sure that you configured connection and socket timeouts for all
  your sql connections.
- Make sure that all your connection-, statement-, and resultset
  objects in java are closed after use (close method is called in a finally
  block).

Comment: no need to deal with ‘close’ in my code as spring handles jdbc related issue for me

Answer (score 0):

This is totally database problem not Tomcat. Database crashes when parameters that you set for database reached to its maximum utilization and there is no more parameters available.

Check your process and session parameters utilization at peak time and set according to their maximum utilization * 5

Comment: but i have 2 applications running on the same web server, both accessing the same DB server. as tomcat1 dies, tomcat2 works well...